# using simplemodal, show loading spinner while content inside iframe loads

Tags: jquery, iframe, spinner, loading, simplemodal

Good morning!

I am using the great [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin for jQuery from Eric Martin.  Currently, I am loading a modal using an iframe to load my requested pages which works as expected.  What I would like to implement is a Loading... spinner which displays while the content is loading.

I am loading my modal as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on click
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        var src = "http://localhost" + $(this).attr("href");
        $.modal('<iframe id="details" class="so" src="' + src + '" height="500"     width="500" style="border:0">', {
            closeHTML: "<a title='Close' class='modalCloseImg simplemodal-close'></a>",
            containerId: "simplemodal-container",
            overlayId: "simplemodal-overlay",
            overlayClose: true
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I have a background image set for my modal-container, which displays right away.  I would definitely prefer to show a loading spinner here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by inserting a loading div inside of the simplemodal source and then calling show/hide as needed from my code.

Answer (score 30):

I am using a slightly extended version of [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) for beautiful spinners and modal spinner overlays. It can be used on any element by simply:

```
$('#ELEMENT_ID').spin()
```

or for modal spinners:

```
$('#ELEMENT_ID').spin("modal")
```

call spin again to turn off and remove the spinner again. This is how it looks like:[image]

This is the spin.min.js including a jQuery extension and some default opts for modal spinners:

```
//fgnass.github.com/spin.js#v1.2.6
!function(e,t,n){function o(e,n){var r=t.createElement(e||"div"),i;for(i in n)r[i]=n[i];return r}function u(e){for(var t=1,n=arguments.length;t<n;t++)e.appendChild(arguments[t]);return e}function f(e,t,n,r){var o=["opacity",t,~~(e*100),n,r].join("-"),u=.01+n/r*100,f=Math.max(1-(1-e)/t*(100-u),e),l=s.substring(0,s.indexOf("Animation")).toLowerCase(),c=l&&"-"+l+"-"||"";return i[o]||(a.insertRule("@"+c+"keyframes "+o+"{"+"0%{opacity:"+f+"}"+u+"%{opacity:"+e+"}"+(u+.01)+"%{opacity:1}"+(u+t)%100+"%{opacity:"+e+"}"+"100%{opacity:"+f+"}"+"}",a.cssRules.length),i[o]=1),o}function l(e,t){var i=e.style,s,o;if(i[t]!==n)return t;t=t.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+t.slice(1);for(o=0;o<r.length;o++){s=r[o]+t;if(i[s]!==n)return s}}function c(e,t){for(var n in t)e.style[l(e,n)||n]=t[n];return e}function h(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var r=arguments[t];for(var i in r)e[i]===n&&(e[i]=r[i])}return e}function p(e){var t={x:e.offsetLeft,y:e.offsetTop};while(e=e.offsetParent)t.x+=e.offsetLeft,t.y+=e.offsetTop;return t}var r=["webkit","Moz","ms","O"],i={},s,a=function(){var e=o("style",{type:"text/css"});return u(t.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],e),e.sheet||e.styleSheet}(),d={lines:12,length:7,width:5,radius:10,rotate:0,corners:1,color:"#000",speed:1,trail:100,opacity:.25,fps:20,zIndex:2e9,className:"spinner",top:"auto",left:"auto"},v=function m(e){if(!this.spin)return new m(e);this.opts=h(e||{},m.defaults,d)};v.defaults={},h(v.prototype,{spin:function(e){this.stop();var t=this,n=t.opts,r=t.el=c(o(0,{className:n.className}),{position:"relative",width:0,zIndex:n.zIndex}),i=n.radius+n.length+n.width,u,a;e&&(e.insertBefore(r,e.firstChild||null),a=p(e),u=p(r),c(r,{left:(n.left=="auto"?a.x-u.x+(e.offsetWidth>>1):parseInt(n.left,10)+i)+"px",top:(n.top=="auto"?a.y-u.y+(e.offsetHeight>>1):parseInt(n.top,10)+i)+"px"})),r.setAttribute("aria-role","progressbar"),t.lines(r,t.opts);if(!s){var f=0,l=n.fps,h=l/n.speed,d=(1-n.opacity)/(h*n.trail/100),v=h/n.lines;(function m(){f++;for(var e=n.lines;e;e--){var i=Math.max(1-(f+e*v)%h*d,n.opacity);t.opacity(r,n.lines-e,i,n)}t.timeout=t.el&&setTimeout(m,~~(1e3/l))})()}return t},stop:function(){var e=this.el;return e&&(clearTimeout(this.timeout),e.parentNode&&e.parentNode.removeChild(e),this.el=n),this},lines:function(e,t){function i(e,r){return c(o(),{position:"absolute",width:t.length+t.width+"px",height:t.width+"px",background:e,boxShadow:r,transformOrigin:"left",transform:"rotate("+~~(360/t.lines*n+t.rotate)+"deg) translate("+t.radius+"px"+",0)",borderRadius:(t.corners*t.width>>1)+"px"})}var n=0,r;for(;n<t.lines;n++)r=c(o(),{position:"absolute",top:1+~(t.width/2)+"px",transform:t.hwaccel?"translate3d(0,0,0)":"",opacity:t.opacity,animation:s&&f(t.opacity,t.trail,n,t.lines)+" "+1/t.speed+"s linear infinite"}),t.shadow&&u(r,c(i("#000","0 0 4px #000"),{top:"2px"})),u(e,u(r,i(t.color,"0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)")));return e},opacity:function(e,t,n){t<e.childNodes.length&&(e.childNodes[t].style.opacity=n)}}),function(){function e(e,t){return o("<"+e+' xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:vml" class="spin-vml">',t)}var t=c(o("group"),{behavior:"url(#default#VML)"});!l(t,"transform")&&t.adj?(a.addRule(".spin-vml","behavior:url(#default#VML)"),v.prototype.lines=function(t,n){function s(){return c(e("group",{coordsize:i+" "+i,coordorigin:-r+" "+ -r}),{width:i,height:i})}function l(t,i,o){u(a,u(c(s(),{rotation:360/n.lines*t+"deg",left:~~i}),u(c(e("roundrect",{arcsize:n.corners}),{width:r,height:n.width,left:n.radius,top:-n.width>>1,filter:o}),e("fill",{color:n.color,opacity:n.opacity}),e("stroke",{opacity:0}))))}var r=n.length+n.width,i=2*r,o=-(n.width+n.length)*2+"px",a=c(s(),{position:"absolute",top:o,left:o}),f;if(n.shadow)for(f=1;f<=n.lines;f++)l(f,-2,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2,makeshadow=1,shadowopacity=.3)");for(f=1;f<=n.lines;f++)l(f);return u(t,a)},v.prototype.opacity=function(e,t,n,r){var i=e.firstChild;r=r.shadow&&r.lines||0,i&&t+r<i.childNodes.length&&(i=i.childNodes[t+r],i=i&&i.firstChild,i=i&&i.firstChild,i&&(i.opacity=n))}):s=l(t,"animation")}(),typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define(function(){return v}):e.Spinner=v}(window,document);

var default_opts = {
        lines: 9,
        length: 2,
        width: 3,
        radius: 8,
        corners: 1,
        rotate: 0,
        color: '#555',
        speed: 1,
        trail: 47,
        shadow: false,
        hwaccel: false,
        className: 'spinner',
        zIndex: 2e9,
        top: 'auto',
        left: 'auto'
};

var modal_opts = {
        lines: 11, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 23, // The length of each line
        width: 8, // The line thickness
        radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 9, // The rotation offset
        color: '#FFF', // #rgb or #rrggbb
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 50, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: true, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
        left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};

//jQuery extension
$.fn.spin = function(opts) {
    if (opts == null) opts = default_opts;
    if (opts == "modal") opts = modal_opts;

    this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data();

        if (data.spinner) {
            data.spinner.stop();
            delete data.spinner;
            if (opts == modal_opts) $("#spin_modal_overlay").remove();
            return this;
        }

        var spinElem = this;
        if (opts == modal_opts){
            $('body').append('<div id="spin_modal_overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:'+(opts.zIndex-1)+'"/>');
            spinElem = $("#spin_modal_overlay")[0];
        }
        data.spinner = new Spinner($.extend({color: $this.css('color')}, opts)).spin(spinElem);
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Did you style #ELEMENT_ID to be centered or something? My spinner is always on top-left side of the screen, no matter how I style it. Current style is: #ELEMENT_ID {transform: translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%; top: 50%; position: fixed;}

Comment: OK, I solved it configuring modal_opts with 'top:50%' and 'left:50%'.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for this is to use a load() and then place the code for the modal in load's callback. Here is an example, pseudo-code -

```
$('.basic').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // use instead of return false
    var src = "http://localhost" + $(this).attr("href");
    $('iframe details').load('loading.html', function() {
        $.modal('<iframe id="det....
```

That way the iFrame loads the page containing the image immediately and then the modal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately that is not quite what I am looking for.  I need to have the loading animation display after simplemodal-overlay and simplemodal-container have been drawn, but before the content of my iframe is displayed.

Comment: Does $.modal have a callback option?